# Given an integer $a$ how to find all integers $b$ such that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=k$ for some integer $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

As stated, I need, for a known integer $a$ to find the integers $b$ that make $a^2+b^2 = k^2$ for some integer $k$.

Alternatively if I can at least find an upper bound for them I can brute force the answer.

EDIT:
$k$ is NOT known, it's an arbitrary integer and can be any integer.

Comment: $a^2 = (k-b)(k+b)$ should help.

Comment: So $a$ and $k$ are known and $b$ is what you're trying to find?

Comment: k is an arbitrary integer, it is not known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#A_variant)) the following parametrization of Pythagorean triples:
\begin{align}
a&=mn&
b&=\frac{m^2-n^2}2&
k&=\frac{m^2+n^2}2
\end{align}
which is valid if $m$ and $n$ are two odd integers such that $m > n$.
If $a$ is odd and you can factor it as $a=mn$ and the obtain $b$ and $k$.

If $a$ is even, write $a=2^e\bar a$ with $\bar a$ odd and apply the formula above with $\bar a$ instead of $a$:
\begin{align}
\bar a&=mn&
\bar b&=\frac{m^2-n^2}2&
\bar k&=\frac{m^2+n^2}2
\end{align}
and take $b=2^e\bar b$ and $k=2^e\bar k$.
Then $(a,b,k)$ gives you all Pythagorean triples.